# What is the performance affect of setting alpha = 0 on a view

Tags: android, performance, gpu

If I set alpha 0 on a view will it be drawn by GPU ? Transparent views have quite a toll on GPU ... I am wondering is it same for a zero alpha view

Comment: you can use `view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` it does the same thing in a better way I suppose

Comment: What's the reason behind this? If you want to hide it, consider setting Visibility?

Comment: Yes setting `INVISIBLE` is better performance, because android will just calculate the space the view would take and not actually render the view as far as I know

Comment: Setting invisible prevents the view from getting clicks. I want it to be invisible yet get clicks

Comment: So you want to create spamware

Comment: What ? @NickCardoso sometimes we need to hack for constructive work as well. And I wont bother about GPU perfomance for creating a spamware lol

Comment: Then if it isnt to trick people, explain a good reason to have a transparent item clickable? Then you might convince  some of the knowledgeable people here to reply